# React-Native: CreateBottomTabBar icon does not render

Tags: react-native

CreateBottomTabBar icons does not render. I've tried it every way. This is happening after react-navigation upgrade to version 4. 
I'm using stack + tabNavigator

https://github.com/brunowbbs/React_Navigation4_Stack-Tabs

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import Tab1 from './Tab1';
import Tab2 from './Tab2';

const tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Tab1:{
        screen:Tab1,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon:() => <Icon size={ 20 } name={ 'home' } color={ 'red' }/>            
        }
    },
    Tab2:{
        screen:Tab2,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarIcon:  <Icon name='search' size={25} color='red'/>
        }
    }
})

export default tabs;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems like a problem not with the react native vector icons.  its the new way it works in with react-native 0.60+..      Auto link for this library is a problem! It does not auto link for me too in android.

so here is what you should do:

1:  cd intoYourProject && react-native link react-native-vector-icons
2:  now go into your android emulator and uninstall the application old build
3:  now again  turn the metro and react-native run-android should be in business and it will fresh install

then this app will show the icons.

## speakingFromExperience

the solution **above will cause a warning about LINKING** if you are using 0.60+ React Native version.

**Here is another nice solution on that part**

just uninstall the app on the mobile and

Then only add

`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`

to **android/app/build.gradle**  at the bottom of the file.

and then just rebuild the app to the phone and you will never see the icon mishap again.  #peace

Answer (score 0):

Could you change this?

```js
tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor, image }) => {
return (
          <Icon
            name={'home' }
            size={horizontal ? 20 : 25}
            color={'red'}
          />
       )
}
```